# Extrapolating learned model with time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, data-science

```
library(astsa)
library(forecast)
globtemp
trend <- tslm(globtemp~I(trend^2)+trend)
autoplot(cbind(globtemp,trend$fitted), lwd=1)
```

How do I extrapolate here? I'd like to draw the "trend line" line further, up to let's say 2031.

[image]

I tried using solution [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848569/extrapolating-time-series):

```
predict(trend, data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"), by="1 year", length.out=10)), interval = "prediction")
```

but it only warned me that `Warning message: 'newdata' had 10 rows but variables found have 136 rows` and gave some gibberish results.

Comment: @slamballais Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

Use `forecast::forecast`:

```
forecast(trend)
```

This returns an object with predicted values for subsequent years as well as confidence intervals that you can then use to create a plot.

If you want to forecast further into the future, say, 50 years:

```
forecast(trend, h = 50)
```

By default, it allows you to plot the forecast with `plot`:

```
plot(forecast(trend, h = 50))
```

[image]